# Passing javascript created table from on html to another html

Tags: javascript, html

**Edit:** problem solved! Credits to @Thennarasan and @SiamakFerdos ,you have my deep gratitude!

**Tips:** when you are not sure if you get the value you intended to, try using

```
console.log(your intended value)
```

to check for it!

---

I am working on project and I need to pass a table from one html to another.

Whole process:

1. I want to create a html file to accept a number from the user as an input to produce a multiplication table.
2. Create an external javascript file that should have a function to generate the multiplication table.
3. Javascript function should contain array variables and loops to perform the operation.
4. Use appropriate user message using alert method.
5. Call the function when the user hits ***Generate Table*** button and  forward results to another html page.

The following is what I have so far:

```js
//This is the Calculation.js

function DisplayTable() {
  var baseNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("baseNumber").value);
  var countMult = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];


  var createMultTable = "<table border='1'>"
  document.write(createMultTable);

  //This will create the table
  //First column is user input, second column is multplier from 1 to 10, third column is results.
  for (var row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    document.write('<tr>' + '</tr>');
    document.write('<td>' + baseNumber + '</td>' + '<td>' + countMult[row] + '</td>' + '<td>' + baseNumber * countMult[row] + '</td>');
  }
  createMultTable += "</table>";
  document.write(createMultTable);
}

document.getElementById("newTable").innerHTML = createMultTable;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- This is the Input.html, it gets a table from Calculation.js and pass it to TableGetter.html -->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Multiplication Table</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
  <script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Calculation.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    Multiplication Table
  </header>

 
  <article>
    <h2>Multiplication Table</h2>
    <form method="link" id="newTable" action="TableGetter.html">
      Enter a number:
      <input type="text" name="numInput" id="baseNumber" placeholder="Please enter an integer!">
      <br>
      <!-- <input id="multTable" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return DisplayTable();"> -->
      <button type="button" name="button" onclick="DisplayTable();">Generate Table</button>
    </form>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

I am struggling at figuring out how to forward the result to TableGetter.html. I need help on writing the ***TableGetter.html*** as well as passing the table to ***TableGetter.html*** when I click ***Generate Table*** button in **Input.html**

Deep gratitude!

Comment: In the Method `DisplayTable();` set the data in the sessionstorage or localstorage and get the item from the storage and display in the TableGetter.html.

Comment: @Thennarasan I think I made some mistake in the `form`, it displays the table but not redirecting to TableGetter.html

Comment: Simple as informed using localstorage using the sample posted by @zer00ne. 2 options 1. change the button to a link and take to that page you want and in that page display the data from localstorage or 2. Use window.location.href and point where you want to take the user and display the data.

Comment: @Thennarasan The Ajax import is too much for newbie like me. The project asks me to do it by clicking the button on page1 and display the table generated by js on page2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to make couple of changes, please exactly copy paste and check.

`calculation.js`

```
function DisplayTable() {
var baseNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("baseNumber").value);
var countMult = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var createMultTable = "<table border='1'>"
document.write(createMultTable);
//This will create the table
//First column is user input, second column is multplier from 1 to 10, third column is results.
for (var row = 0; row < 10; row++) {      
  createMultTable += '<tr><td>' + baseNumber + '</td>' + '<td>' + countMult[row] + '</td>' + '<td>' + baseNumber * countMult[row] + '</td></tr>';    

}
createMultTable += "</table>";
localStorage.setItem("table_html", createMultTable);//ADD THIS LINE****

var url = 'TableGetter.html';//WRITE HERE YOUR RIGHT URL
window.location.href = url;
}

if (window.location.pathname ==    "/C:/Users/Thennarasan/Desktop/js/TableGetter.html"){
var data = localStorage.getItem("table_html");
document.getElementById("newTable").innerHTML = data;
}
```

Note change the `window.location.pathname` of what you have.

`input.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- This is the Input.html, it gets a table from Calculation.js and pass it to TableGetter.html -->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Multiplication Table</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
<script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Calculation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
Multiplication Table
</header>
<article>
<h2>Multiplication Table</h2>
<form method="link" id="newTable" action="TableGetter.html">
  Enter a number:
  <input type="text" name="numInput" id="baseNumber" placeholder="Please enter an integer!">
  <br>
  <!-- <input id="multTable" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return DisplayTable();"> -->
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="DisplayTable();">Generate Table</button>
 </form>
</article>
</body>

</html>
```

`TableGetter.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- This is the Input.html, it gets a table from Calculation.js and pass it to TableGetter.html -->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Multiplication Table</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
<script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
Multiplication Table
</header>
<article>
<h2>Multiplication Table</h2>
<div id="newTable"></div>
</article>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Calculation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Run it, it will work as expected.

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you for helping me so much! Can I select both of you and @Siamak as the correct answer? I just used console.log and found out my table object is incomplete. `tr` and `td` scattered everywhere...Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

On TableGetter.html:

```
<script>
    (function() {
        document.getElementById("newTable").innerHTML =   localStorage.getItem("table_html");
    })();   
</script>
```

And change your DisplayTable function:

```
function DisplayTable() {
  var baseNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("baseNumber").value);
  var countMult = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];


  var createMultTable = "<table border='1'>"
  document.write(createMultTable);

  //This will create the table
  //First column is user input, second column is multplier from 1 to 10, third column is results.
  for (var row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    document.write('<tr>' + '</tr>');
    document.write('<td>' + baseNumber + '</td>' + '<td>' + countMult[row] + '</td>' + '<td>' + baseNumber * countMult[row] + '</td>');
  }
  createMultTable += "</table>";

  localStorage.setItem("table_html", createMultTable);//ADD THIS LINE****

  var url = 'TableGetter.html';//WRITE HERE YOUR RIGHT URL
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: Did I make some mistake in the `form`? I can display the table but the URL says its still input.html while it is supposed to jump to TableGetter.html.

Comment: You didn't redirect to new page at all! I append it to your function...

Comment: Is there something involved with input.html? Or is there something wrong the `createMultTable`? Nothing displays when I reach TableGetter.html. I tested it on Firefox, and found the process has three layers. First I click the button, it display the table on input.html for less than 1 sec, then redirects me to TableGetter.html with nothing on there.

Comment: @PsychoLi There's no wrong ting here! May be it couldn't find `newTabl` element in `TableGetter.html`.  Use console.log(localStorage.getItem("table_html")) to insure you can get html.

Comment: @SiamakFerdos in the javascript we need to change the for loop as posted as a new answer other wise in localstorage it will set only `"<table border='1'></table>"`

Comment: In the new page of newtable.html we need to load the calculation.js file last and not on the top. other wise it wil throw null exception in innerhtml. Refer the answer posted.

Comment: @Thennarasan But I don't think it be needed to load `Calculation.js`. This file act as table html generater in first file and put the result in local storage then redirect new html file. New file just read storage and put it into body as I've understood.

Comment: @SiamakFerdos @Thennarasan I found the problem. `console.log` does show that a table is passed to TableGetter.html. But that table is not complete, therefore nothing displays. In my for loop both `tr` and `td` are not added to `createMultTable`, I tried use `+=` to connect `tr` and `td` to `createMultTable`, and now it works!

Comment: @SiamakFerdos Thank you so much for mentioning `console.log` to check, otherwise I would still struggling with the `form`.